# Denoise node not working

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes, viewlayers

I'm still a beginner in blender. But I have a question for the rendering options. After rendering a image there is a option to view different layers. One is the View Layer. Another one is the Composite. I don't really understand what these two layers are doing. Can someone explain this to me?

[image: Layers]

Also why is my Denoise node not removing noise?

@Duarte Farrajota Ramos ♦ has said

> Composite is the final result of rendering with all its node, which may include the result of rendering several distinct View Layers. The other listed View Layer will display the result of each individual view layer you have setup in you scene. In this case since you don't seem to have created any custom View Layers it displays only one View Layer which is the default one

But I have a denoise node. But *View Layer* has no noise. But the *Composite* has noise in the image. If *Composite* has rendered all nodes. Why does it has noise? And why does *View Layer* has no noise? I have uploaded my blend file to pasteall.org the link is in the comments.

`Composite`:
[image: Composite layer]

`View Layer`:
[image: View layer]

If you zoom in you can see the difference.

Comment: Composite is the final result of rendering with all its node, which may include the result of rendering several distinct *View Layers*. The other listed *View Layer* will display the result of each individual view layer you have setup in you scene. In this case since you don't seem to have created any custom *View Layers* it displays only one *View Layer* which is the default one

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos so I have a denoise node. But I'm really confused. The *View Layer* has no noise. But the *Composite* has noise in the image. If *Composite* has rendered all nodes. Why does it has noise? And why does *View Layer* has no noise?

Comment: Impossible to say without looking at your setup

Comment: Here is the blend file: https://pasteall.org/media/9/9/9963dfb33143503fcd3dcd6e5e875dda.blend

Comment: I'm sorry, but I just rendered your file and I honestly can't see the difference between the View Layer combined output and the composite output.  Are you sure you're seeing one?

Comment: @MartyFouts I added the images into my post. So you can check the difference. And this is also how it looks like after the render.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This peculiarity comes about because you have also activated *OpenImageDenoise* in the *Render Properties*.

[image]

The result already denoised by *OpenImageDenoise* is displayed in the *View Layer*. In your composite nodes, however, you use the original *Noisy Image* and denoise it with the node `Denoise` in the Compositing Nodetree, which is output in the *Composite* output.

Since you have also selected the option *Fast*, the result is correspondingly worse than the image denoised by *OpenImageDenoise* visible in *View Layers*.

If you instead turn off *Denoise* in the Render Properties and select *Accurate* in the `Denoise` node, the result will only be denoised by the `Denoise` node and it will look as you expect: *View Layer* is not denoised, but *Composite* output is, with accurate prefiltering by the node `Denoise`.

[image]